# Is there metric learning in MXNet or Keras?

Tags: keras, mxnet

I'm looking for something like this:

- https://github.com/rksltnl/Deep-Metric-Learning-CVPR16

but with MXnet or Keras.

Answer (score 1):

I found some examples in this repository:

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/examples

Maybe it's what you are looking for.

**Edit:**

You can search in the Keras documentation

I made a search for "learning image embeddings" and found some articles:
https://keras.io/search.html?q=learning+image+embeddings

Sorry if I can't provide some code about this, I never worked with deep learning codes. Hope it helps.

Comment: The Word embdedding example doesn't count, I'm looking for learning image embeddings.

Comment: @Nimrod, still wrong. :) Its about manifold extraction. Also known methods are MDS, Kernel clustering, etc.Here a paper on the requested topic: https://cs.adelaide.edu.au/~carneiro/publications/smart-mining-deep.pdf However, I am also looking for an easy way to use this in keras.